# Is there any significant difference between `if [ -a FILE ]` and `if [ -e FILE ]`

Tags: bash, files

I only want to check in bash if a certain FILE exists.
On [this page](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html) two options are mentioned to use with `if`:

- `[ -a FILE ]` - True if FILE exists
- `[ -e FILE ]` - True if FILE exists

Are they equivalent or is there any difference between them?

Comment: I think you can read link :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321348/bash-if-a-vs-e-option, you can see difference between -a and -e.

Comment: Thanks @Tannetto so it seems "saver" to me using `-e` option in order to avoid the confusion with the `-a` meaning `AND`

Comment: @Tannetto nice find. You might want to reproduce a version of that answer here - (if you are copying, please use blockquote formatting and correct attribution)

Comment: @derHugo yes, it seems like `-a` is deprecated as its output may be unreliable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## What  does -a do and why does it exist  ?

The `-a` option is the same thing as `-e`, and exists for compatibility with Korn Shell from which Bash borrowed a lot of features.

From POSIX standard, description of `test` command([link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html)):

> An early proposal used the KornShell -a primary (with the same meaning), but this was changed to -e because there were concerns about the high probability of humans confusing the -a primary with the -a binary operator.

**side note**: binary means flag that appears between two variables `[ $var1 -a $var2  ]`, primary means appearing in the list of arguments first as in `[ -a $var ]`

In fact, Korn Shell (`ksh93` here) manual states:

> -a file
>
> Same as -e below.  This is obsolete.

The `test` command that is used in the [TLDP article you referenced](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html) uses bash built-in `test` , however the option is also present in `/usr/bin/test` despite missing from documentation:

```
$ /usr/bin/test -a /etc/passwd  && echo 1                                   
1
```

## If functionality is the same, is it good idea to use it?

So long as you are 100% sure your scripts will be used on either Bash or Korn Shell - then yes, it is alright.  However, if you strive for portability of your scripts and want to write script the Right Way<sup>TM</sup>, you should use `-e`. The standard Ubuntu shell, `/bin/sh`, which is actually Dash - Debian Amquist Shell - doesn't recognize that as valid option:

```
$ dash
$ test -a /etc/passwd
dash: 1: test: -a: unexpected operator
```

In cases where you want to port your script to other platforms, using `-a` is not guaranteed to be safe with `/usr/bin/test` as well, and you should stick with `-e` because it is in fact specified by POSIX standard.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this background knowledge. Though my question was actually already solved by @Tannetto I accepted your answer as solution since it explains well in an understandable way why it's better to use `-e` ;)