# Is there a file exists command in Ubuntu Terminal?

Tags: command-line

Is there somehow I can check if a file or folder exists in Ubuntu Terminal?

Comment: How can you mark a question as duplicate and point to a question that has -3 raiting??

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use the **`test`** command of the shell `bash`.

```
$ test -e ~/.bashrc && echo file exists || echo file not found
file exists
$ test -e ~/.bashrcx && echo file exists || echo file not found
file not found
```

The command

```
help test
```

prints a help text with the different options, that you can use with the `test` command.

You may also find the following help texts useful, as well as the links in a comment by @dessert,

```
help [
```

and

```
help [[
```

---

You can use the **`find`** command if you don't know where the file is (so that you must search for it in several directories) or you want to find different versions of the file.

```
$ sudo find / -name .bashrc
[sudo] password for sudodus: 
/etc/skel/.bashrc
/root/.bashrc
find: ”/run/user/1002/gvfs”: Permission denied
/media/multimed-2/test/test/2015-04/colour-prompt/home/guru/.bashrc
/media/multimed-2/test/test/2015-04/colour-prompt/root/.bashrc
/media/multimed-2/test/test/2015-04/colour-prompt/etc/skel/.bashrc
/media/multimed-2/rsync-bup/nio/.bashrc
/home/lfs/.bashrc
/home/myself/.bashrc
/home/nio/.bashrc
/home/sudodus/.bashrc
```

Comment: I'd recommend using -e instead. See https://askubuntu.com/a/970306/295286

Comment: Another notation of the `test` command is e.g. `[ -e ~/.bashrc ] && …`, a very good manual can be found on [wiki.bash-hackers.org](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest). `test` should not be confused with its modern counterpart, the [conditional expression](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression), e.g. `[[ -e ~/.bashrc ]] && …`. The last is much more powerful in many ways, allowing the use of extended regular expressions for instance.

Comment: @dessert, I find it easy to understand and remember `test` as described in my answer, when checking for the existence of files. In other cases, for example in `if` statements I use the syntax that you describe in your comment. I guess it depends on how I learned using these things ...

Comment: `-e` tests for raw existence, `-f` and `-d` additionally test whether it's a file or directory respectively.

Comment: @sudodus I just wanted to add this as you often see it in scripts etc. It may confuse people that `[` actually is a command exactly like e.g. `mv`. The conditional expression by the way is *not* a command, which is why you can use `&&` inside it – I really prefer this notation over `-a`.

Comment: @dessert, thank you for adding these helpful comments :-)

Comment: There is also `locate`, which locates all files that have searched string in the name. `locate` uses its own database of filenames. Search is much faster than find, but it can miss newly created files if `updatedb` did not yet reindex the files. `updatedb` is a program that scans the disk and updates the database of files. You can start it by typing `sudo updatedb`. It is also executed regularly on its own (`/etc/cron.daily/mlocate`).

Comment: @nobody, Thank you for adding this useful comment :-)

Comment: There is also `ls`: `ls /var/www 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null && echo 'file exists' || echo 'file not found'`